# Tkinter: Getting value from one function and using it in another function

Tags: python, tkinter

In Python `tkinter`, I want to get the value from an `Entry` widget that is in one function and use that value in another function, but I am unable to do so. Here is my code:

```
def login():
    print("This is your username: " + username_entry.get())
    print("This is your password: " + password_entry.get())

def login_screen()
    username_label = Label(root, text="Username", font=6)
    username_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=80)

    username_entry = Entry(root, font=6)
    username_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, padx=80)

    password_label = Label(root, text="Password", font=6)
    password_label.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5, padx=80)

    password_entry = Entry(root, font=6)
    password_entry.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=5, padx=80)
    
    login_button = Button(root, text="Login",font=3, command=login)
    login_button.grid(row=7, column=0,  pady=(10,5), padx=80)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask a question*, keeping in mind that this is *not a discussion forum*. "I would really appreciate your help" is not a question but [off-topic conversation that we aren't interested in](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions/260778#260778), and "I am unable to do so" *does not describe the problem*. How exactly do you attempt to use the program? What happens when you do so? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. We don't need your whole actual program, but we do need enough surrounding code to make a sensible program that is complete by itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you just want the entries available to the `login()` function, you can pass them in as parameters:

```py
def login(username_entry, password_entry):
    print("This is your username: " + username_entry.get())
    print("This is your password: " + password_entry.get())

def login_screen()
    username_label = Label(root, text="Username", font=6)
    username_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=80)

    username_entry = Entry(root, font=6)
    username_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, padx=80)

    password_label = Label(root, text="Password", font=6)
    password_label.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5, padx=80)

    password_entry = Entry(root, font=6)
    password_entry.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=5, padx=80)

    login_button = Button(root, text="Login",font=3,
                          command=lambda: login(username_entry, password_entry))
    login_button.grid(row=7, column=0,  pady=(10,5), padx=80)
```

Here I've used a `lambda` to defer the execution of the `login` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should return values that you want to use in other place.
or use a class, or a global variable.

Comment: `return` them from what? When?